# How do I invert the Y Axis for iPhone / backbone for Call Of Duty Mobile

Tags: controllers, ios, call-of-duty, call-of-duty-mobile

I have a backbone game controller for the iPhone (it's nice) and I want to play Call Of Duty Mobile, but the game has no setting for inverting the Y Axis. What other options are there? Are there options for any controller in general?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution that works for the backbone and maybe any controller. On iOS 14.6 you can use the iOS settings app to invert the Y Axis for any game.

**This works for the Backbone and general controllers.**

1. Attach the Backbone. Or Connect your controller.
2. On your iOS device's open the Settings app.
3. Touch the "General" option.
4. Scroll down a little and touch the "Game Controller" option.
5. There are several options but we are only interested in one of them.
6. Touch the "Customizations" option.
7. At the Top of the screen turn on "Enable Customizations".
8. You can customize the settings for all games here. OR Customize for a specific game.
9. For a specific game scroll all the way to the bottom and touch "Add App" and Select your App.
10. Scroll down and touch "Right Thumbstick".
11. Turn on "Invert Vertically".

Happy Gaming!

Answer (score 1):

Well great! There is now a setting in CoD:M. In game push the very tiny gear icon. Then on the top across all the tabs there is one called "Controller". (you might have to drag the tabs to the left to see it.) The invert options are in there.